# Using NSPredicate with NSFetchRequest in a NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am learning CoreData and I wanted to have my code reviewed.  As usual, I get something to work, then I attempt to refine it.
I have a data model that consists of an Item entity and a subItem entity.  The Item has a 'to many' relationship with the subItem and subItem has a 'to one' relationship with Item.  Basically Item can have multiple subitems, but subitem can only be tied to one Item.  My initial tableview displays the items and selecting a row segues to a tabbarcontroller that consists of other controllers, one being another tableview.  That tableview displays the subitems of the Item.  This is the code I have in my viewDidLoad:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *subItemEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"KFPSubItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:subItemEntity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item = %@", self.record];

//add sort descriptors
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];

//initialize fetchedresultscontroller
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

//configure fetched results controller
[self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];


//perform Fetch
NSError *error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entity and the sort descriptors of `NSFetchRequest` are defined as "properties"

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSEntityDescription *entity;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sortDescriptors;
```

So while calling the setter methods still works

```
[fetchRequest setEntity:...];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:...];
```

you should use the "dot-Syntax" for properties:

```
fetchRequest.entity = ...;
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = ...;
```

and the same applies to the properties of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

The creation of the fetch request can be simplified with the
factory method

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"KFPSubItem"];
```

I usually assign the sort descriptors to separate variables first. This may
be a matter of taste, but it avoids too long statements if there is more
than one sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortByName];
```

The

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] ...
```

line is extremely long and should be split into several lines.

The correct way to check for success or failure of Cocoa (Touch) methods is 
documented in
["Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) in the "Error Handling Programming Guide":

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the
>   method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in
>   the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the
>   method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should
>   always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to
>   do anything with the NSError object.

So instead of

```
NSError *error = nil;
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
if (error) { ... }
```

you should do

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) { .... }
```

Putting it all together:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"KFPSubItem"];

NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortByName];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item = %@", self.record];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                           cacheName:nil];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to perform fetch");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Comment: Greatly Appreciated!  That is so much more efficient and looks much better!

Comment: Hi Martin, Can I ask the reason behind using dot-syntax for the setters? I still use the explicit 'set' in the square brackets but was wondering if there are reasons apart from readability?

Comment: @Tim: There is actually no functional difference, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249392/dot-notation-vs-message-notation-for-declared-properties and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259946/objective-c-message-syntax-vs-dot-syntax-whats-the-difference. I prefer the dot notation for properties because you can directly see that you are working with a property and not with arbitrary methods. (And in Apple's "next generation language" Swift, there is only dot notation for properties.)